# Include function inside a some function

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs

I am getting a json object for my role guard and I am trying to check and see if the user has a set of roles where one of them is in the list of accepted roles for the action. I have the function set up as follows:

```
export class RoleGuard implements CanActivate{
constructor (private readonly reflector: Reflector, readonly jwtService: JwtService) {}
public canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): boolean {
    const roles = this.reflector.get<string[]>('groups', context.getHandler());
    if (!roles) {
        return true;
    }
    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    const user: any = this.jwtService.decode(request.headers.authorization.substr(7), { json: true, complete: true });
    // tslint:disable-next-line:ter-arrow-parens
    const hasGroup = () => user.payload.groups.some((role: any) => roles.includes(role));
    return user && user.payload.groups && hasGroup();
```

user.payload.groups is the array of the roles the user has and "roles" is the list of accepted roles that can perform the action. However every time that the program runs it fails even with the right role. What is happening here that I am not seeing? I got this from the documentation from the nestjs website: https://docs.nestjs.com/guards

example for groups object:

```
Array(3) ["role1", "role2", "role3"]
length:3
__proto__:Array(0) [, …]
0:"role1"
1:"role2"
2:"role3"
```

example for roles object:

```
Array(2) ["role4", "role3"]
length:2
__proto__:Array(0) [, …]
0:"role4"
1:"role3"
```

Comment: The two arrays contain only strings or role objects?  Probably, you're comparing objects and not strings.

Comment: Thanks for asking a question!  Since you are having a code problem, please review what constitutes a [mcve] so that you can get a meaningful answer.

Comment: could you rpovide an example of `role` object

Comment: sorry about that I provided an example of the two object that i am working with and the implementation i am using for my roleguard

Comment: You're facing another problem for sure.

Comment: darn i was afraid that was the case

Comment: Just checked something out if I add another item to the "roles" object so there are 3 items it works only when there are 2 is when it stops working.

Comment: Instead of editing your question post your solution as an answer and accept it so that others can see that your problem was solved. :-)

Answer (score 0):

So I found out the issue had nothing to do with the role guard code. That is working fine the problem was with a mismatch in the role names. My friend and I resolved the names and all is working fine. I am a bit embarrassed, Thank you for all the help that was provided.